# Overriding static members in derived classes in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance, static

```
<?php
class Base {
  protected static $c = 'base';

  public static function getC() {
    return self::$c;
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  protected static $c = 'derived';
}

echo Base::getC(); // output "base"
echo Derived::getC();    // output "base", but I need "derived" here!
?>
```

So what's the best workaround?

Comment: replace self::$c with static::$c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to upgrade to PHP 5.3, where [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) are available. If that's not an option, you'll unfortunately have to redesign your class.

Comment: Is PHP 5.3 compatible with PHP 5.2? My server is still running on 5.2

Comment: @powerboy It is **backwards** compatible, meaning scripts written for 5.2 will run on 5.3, for the largest part. Some minor things may have changed. See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php

Answer (score 4):

Based on deceze's and Undolog's input:
Undolog is right, for PHP <= 5.2 .

But with 5.3 and late static bindings it will work , just use static instead of self inside the function - now it will work...//THX @ deceze for the hint

for us copy past sample scanning stackoverflow users - this will work:

```php
class Base {
  protected static $c = 'base';
  public static function getC() {
    return static::$c; // !! please notice the STATIC instead of SELF !!
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  protected static $c = 'derived';
}

echo Base::getC();      // output "base"
echo Derived::getC();   // output "derived"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-implment base class method; try with:

```
class Derived extends Base {
  protected static $c = 'derived';

  public static function getC() {
    return self::$c;
  }
}
```

As you see, this solution is very useless, because force to re-write all subclassed methods.

The value of `self::$c` depends only on the class where the method was actually implemented, not the class from which it was called.